# Bug in _getEncodedApiKey($apiKey) since 1.9?

Tags: api, bug, ce-1.9.0.1

I was (and still am) struggling to login using the magento api. Thereby I noticed, that

```
Mage_Api_Model_User::_getEncodedApiKey($apiKey)
```

got slightly changed

from:

```
protected function _getEncodedApiKey($apiKey)
    {
        return $this->_getHelper('core')->getHash($apiKey, 2);
    }
```

to

```
protected function _getEncodedApiKey($apiKey)
    {
        return $this->_getHelper('core')->getHash($apiKey, Mage_Admin_Model_User::HASH_SALT_LENGTH);
    }
```

In my case, this always leads to `false` in

```
if ($this->authenticate($username, $apiKey))
```

Any thoughts?